# I get empty page when trying to show a list of child objects filtered by parent id. Using linkTo. Only works when refresh browser

Tags: ember.js

I am getting to know Ember JS. I am trying to have a list of Accounts, and beside each account I want a link to navigate to a list of Transactions of that account. 
When I load the first page requesting /accounts , I successfully get my list of accounts. But when I click

```
{{#linkTo transactions this}}see transactions{{/linkTo}}
```

the browser URl goes to /#/transactions/1, but I get an empty page. If I load this URL directly in the browser, everything works properly. But going from accounts list and clicking in one account, I get nothing.

The Accounts template is as follows:

```
<ul id="conta-list">
    {{#each controller}}
        <li>
            Account: {{name}} {{#linkTo transactions this}}see transactions{{/linkTo}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The Transactions template is:

```
<ul>
    {{#each controller}}
        <li>
            {{description}} = ${{value}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Application code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('accounts');
  this.route('transactions', { path: '/transactions/:account_id' });
});

App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Account.find();
  }
});

App.TransactionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return App.Transaction.find({ account_id: params.account_id });
    }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Transaction = DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  value: DS.attr('number'),
  account: DS.belongsTo('App.Account')
});
```

I get "Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' " in console.

The route /transactions/:account_id only hits the server if I reload the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get "Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' " in console.

This is because the linkTo helper is passing an account to the transactions route, but your template is expecting the transactions model to be an array of transactions.

> If I load this URL directly in the browser, everything works properly. But going from accounts list and clicking in one account, I get nothing.

So when you visit via url the route's model hook is called, `App.Transaction.find` makes a request to the server and everything works. By design none of this happens when following a link - instead you pass context arguments to the linkTo helper and those arguments are used to set the route's model. So in this case ember router does not call the route's model hook.

The *ember way* to make this work is by modeling transactions as a nested resource. So your route's would look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('accounts');
  this.resource('account', { path: '/account/:account_id' }, function() {
    this.route('transactions');
  });
});
```

With this approach you can use the auto-generated Account route but will need to define an AccountTransactions route.

```
App.AccountTransactionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.modelFor("account").get('transactions');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. The relation between the two models is onde direction only. It is a many-to-one. So Account does not know about its transactions. So I suppose I just need to change the return of your model hook in App.AccountTransactionsRoute right? Tks

Comment: Tried it and it works. Thanks. But I get this log in the console before transitioning to account.transactions
WARNING: The immediate parent route ('application') did not render into the main outlet and the default 'into' option ('account') may not be expected. Know what it is?

Comment: Glad that worked. The warning is not a big deal, it's letting you know that ember expected to render 'transactions' template into 'account.hbs', but since it could not find that template it was rendered into 'application'